# Overwrite HQL-generation for FetchMany()

Tags: nhibernate, hql, linq-to-nhibernate

I know that I can extend NHibernates HQL-generation to support new methods as described in [this article](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.de/2010/07/nhibernate-linq-provider-extension.html). If I implement `IRuntimeMethodHqlGenerator` it will also work for generic methods.

But is there a way to overwrite NHibernate's default behavior for already supported methods? In this specific case I want to overwrite how NHibernate deals with calls to `FetchMany()`.

Just hooking up a custom generator doesn't work as it is never called.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but you might want to have a look at the NHibernate Linq Inner Join Fetch provider project for guidance: https://github.com/eallegretta/nhibernate-linq-innerjoin-fetch

Comment: @DanP Thanks, that one really helped. Pity they have to use Reflection to hookup custom extension methods. If you make your comment an answer I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but you might want to have a look at the [NHibernate Linq Inner Join Fetch provider](https://github.com/eallegretta/nhibernate-linq-innerjoin-fetch) project for guidance.